# Geom point visualization issue in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is question linked to previous question (Adjusting legend.title ,legend.text and legend color in ggplot2). I am having issue to change color of the geom points (Run and Walk Segmentation) in the plot. Can anyone please help me in this ? Is there any other way that i can have more better visualizations for the segmentation ? Thanks

```
  er<-  ggmap(sq_map2) + 
  geom_point(data = sisquoc, size = 8,  aes(fill = Segmentation)) +  
  geom_line(data = sisquoc, size = 3,  aes(color =SpeedMeterPerSecond)) +
  geom_text(data = sisquoc, aes(label = paste("  ", 
                                             as.character(Location_ids), 
  sep="")), 
           angle = 60, hjust = 0, color = "sienna4",size = 6 ) 

   gg<- er  +   labs(x ="Longitude", y = "Latitude") +
   theme(axis.title = element_text(size=20), 
       panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white",size = 0.5, linetype = 
                                         "dotted"),
       panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.5, linetype = 
   'dotted',colour 
                                       = "black"), 
       panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.5, linetype = 
   'dotted',colour 
                                       = "black"),
       panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=0.5),
       axis.text.y   = element_text(size=18),
       axis.text.x   = element_text(size=18))

    gg  + theme(legend.position="right", 
           legend.title = element_text(colour="Black", size=18),
           legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size = 15),
           legend.background = element_rect(fill="grey90",
                                            size=0.5, linetype="solid", 
                                            colour ="black"))  + 
    scale_color_continuous(name="Speed (m/s)\n")
```

Comment: ```sq_map2`` sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want to change the colour of the points in the plot.
try `+ scale_fill_manual(values = c("Run" = "black","Walk" = "grey"))`

Comment: I have added this line but the color is not changing.                   geom_point(data = sisquoc, size = 8,  aes(fill = Segmentation))+ scale_fill_manual(values = c("Run" = "Red","Walk" = "Green"))

Answer (score 1):

For `geom_point` to make use of `aes(fill=...)` you have to select shapes that can take fill values in addition to colour values, otherwise `geom_point` takes `aes(colour=...)`.  Fill is the appropriate `aes` to use here since you are already making use of `aes(colour=...)` for `geom_line`.

See possible shapes 21 to 25 that take fill values [here](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/shape)

Try:

```
ggmap(sq_map2) + 
  geom_point(data = sisquoc, size = 8,  aes(fill = Segmentation, shape = Segmentation) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21, 24))
```

You can further define fill values using e.g. `scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "blue"))`

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)